# Some divs not displaying border

Tags: html, css, border

I'm experiencing this weird issue where some borders on the exact same divs are not being displayed... I've spent hours now trying to figure this out, for some reason zooming in/out will occasionally have it appearing/disappearing. I'm thinking it has something to do with the flexboxes maybe? Notice in this example I've posted the first div is displaying a top border, but the second is not. They're the exact same div... I don't get it. I'd appreciate a second look, thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/kcaej1nz/

```
<div class="CONTAINER">


  <div class="child_4a">
    <div class="homecontent-mid">
      <div class="sliderdiv"><img src="images/black.png" alt="test1"></div>
      <div class="main-search">
      <div class="new-title"><a href="">Title 2</a><br><span class="contact-article">7/17/2019 by: <a href="contact">Ian</a></span><br>
        <p class="pale-goddess">Short sentence 2.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="child_4a">
    <div class="homecontent-mid">
      <div class="sliderdiv"><img src="images/black.png" alt="test1"></div>
      <div class="main-search">
      <div class="new-title"><a href="">Title 3</a><br><span class="contact-article">7/17/2019 by: <a href="contact">Ian</a></span><br>
        <p class="pale-goddess">Short sentence 3.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can see the border with a zoom level of 100% but not with a zoom-level of 90%. Could you confirm this issue is not browser setting related?

Comment: I can see it happen on W10 Firefox too, resizing the output window shows the border on and off. I changed the border temporarily from `thin` to `5px` and it seems that `.child_4a` has some overlap issue. Just changing `thin` to `1px` (like answered) will not solve the problem. Going to have a closer look...

Comment: Remove `height: inherit;` in `.main-search` and the border will be shown consistently with any zoom level.

Comment: For starters: remove 4 times `background-color: none` (incorrect value) or use `transparent` (which is HTML default for an element, so, just remove). [w3schools: CSS background-color Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp)

Comment: element `.main-search` overflows somehow and `.homecontent-mid {...overflow: hidden...}` obfuscates that. Move `overflow: hidden` from `.homecontent-mid` to `.main-search` and the erratic behaviour stops. This is the least amount of modification to your original source. However, element `.main-search` should not overflow, so we're not done yet....BTW, are you new to FBL? (Which is cool, of course, but I see rather 'uncommon' use of flexbox...)

Comment: Yeah, I'm new to web dev, only been at it for a couple weeks now..

Answer (score 0):

Give the border width in px as

```
border-top: 1px solid #00000069;
```

Comment: 1px will not help against subpixel rendering.

Comment: I originally was using 1px but was having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the subpixel rendering. It helps to add space (via margin):

```
  .main-search {
        ...
        border-top: 1px solid #00000069;
        margin-top:2px;
  }
```

I tested this with chrome at different zooming levels. It works fine.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work, thanks much for the assistance.

Comment: That's fine. Can you mark my answer as 'solved'. Thx!